# C++ How to write a code that counts top words while removing any special characters from text file

Tags: c++

How do I take a text file from the command line that opens and reads it, and then count the top words in that file but also removes any special characters. I have this code done here and used maps but it isn't counting every word. For instance "hello." is one word and also "$#%hello<>?/". I have this file from the song shake it off that's supposed to read shake 78 times but I only counted 26 in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string ask(const string& msg) {
  string ans;
  cout << msg;
  getline(cin, ans);
  return ans;
}
int main() {

  ifstream fin( ask("Enter file name: ").c_str() ) ;
  if (fin.fail()) {
    cerr << "ERROR"; // this is if the file fails to open
    return 1;
  }
  map<string, int> wordCount;
  string entity;
  while (fin >> entity) {
    vector<string> words;

for (int i = 0, a = 0; i < entity.length(); i++) {
  char& c = entity[i];
  if (c < 'A' || (c > 'Z' && c < 'a') || c > 'z') {
    string word = entity.substr(a, i - a);
    a = i + 1;
    if (word.length() > 0)
      words.push_back(word);
  }
}
for (auto & word : words)
  wordCount[word]++;

}
fin.close();

vector<string> topWords;
const size_t MAX_WORDS = 10;
for ( auto iter = wordCount.begin(); iter != wordCount.end(); iter ++ ) {

int som = 0, lim = topWords.size();
while (som < lim) {
  int i = ( som + lim ) / 2;
  int count = wordCount[topWords[i]];
  if ( iter -> second > count)
    lim = i;
  else if ( iter -> second < count )
    som = i + 1;
  else
    som = lim = i;

}
if (som < MAX_WORDS ) {
  topWords.insert( topWords.begin() + som, iter -> first );
  if ( topWords.size() > MAX_WORDS )
    topWords.pop_back();
}
}
for (auto & topWord : topWords)
  cout << "(" << wordCount[topWord] << ")\t" << topWord << endl;




return 0;

}
```

One last thing if yall can probably help me on is how would I also write a code that takes a number from the command line alongside the filename and with that number, display the number of top words corresponding with that number passed in the command line, I would assume there is a parse args involved maybe.
Thank you again!

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mimirplatform.production/files/48a9fa64-cddc-4e45-817f-3e16bd7772c2/shake_it_off.txt

```
!hi!
@hi@
#hi#
$hi$
%hi%
^hi^
&hi&
*hi*
(hi(
)hi)
_hi_
-hi-
+hi+
=hi=
~hi~
`hi`
:hi:
;hi;
'hi'
"hi"
<hi<
>hi>
/hi/
?hi?
{hi{
}hi}
[hi[
]hi]
|hi|
\hi\

bob bob bob bob bob bob bob !@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":bob@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":
!@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":bob@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":  !@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":bob@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":
!@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":bob@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:": !@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:":bob@#@$$%#&@^*()@*#)_++(#<><#:
```

this is the special character test

Comment: What about just [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and supply a predicate that uses `!std::isalpha` -- see the example near the bottom of the linked page that uses the erase-remove idiom.

Comment: Looking at your actual code, you have a pretty wild test going on: `if (c < 'A' || (c > 'Z' && c < 'a') || c > 'z')` -- this is NOT cool.  Why not either use `if (!std::isalpha(c))` or `if (!(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))`

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is somewhat hard to refine, I have followed your description to get a program that uses STL.

- Combine `erase` with `remove_if` to remove unwanted chars
- Use `set` to resort by counts

If you have some experience with Boost, it's a use case with `multimap` or `bimap`, which can make the code even more cleaner.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string ask(const string& msg) {
  string ans;
  cout << msg;
  getline(cin, ans);
  return ans;
}
int main() {
  // ifstream fin(ask("Enter file name: ").c_str());
  ifstream fin("shake_it_off.txt");
  if (fin.fail()) {
    cerr << "ERROR";  // this is if the file fails to open
    return 1;
  }
  map<string, size_t> wordCount;
  string entity;

  while (fin >> entity) {
    entity.erase(std::remove_if(entity.begin(), entity.end(),
                                [](char ch) { return !isalpha(ch); }),
                 entity.end());
    wordCount[entity] += 1;
  }

  auto cmp = [](const std::pair<std::string, size_t>& lhs,
                const std::pair<std::string, size_t>& rhs) {
    return lhs.second > rhs.second;
  };
  std::multiset<std::pair<std::string, size_t>, decltype(cmp)> top(
      wordCount.begin(), wordCount.end(), cmp);
  auto it = top.begin();
  const size_t MAX_WORDS = 10;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS && it != top.end(); ++i, ++it) {
    cout << "(" << it->first << ")\t" << it->second << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return !isalpha(ch); ` -- Should be `return !static_cast<int>(isalpha(ch));`